# How can I call the Control color, I mean the default forms color?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

For instance, to make something blue I would go:

```
this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
```

How can I summon the Control color, the khaki one.

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The `System.Drawing.SystemColors` class has properties exposing the various system colours, so you can do

```
this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```

The full range of properties to access other colours is listed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors_members.aspx).

Comment: this.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true; sets if back to the default color

Answer (score 14):

I haven't tested this, but I believe it to be:

```
this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
```

Comment: Tested and works fine! better than accepted answer, since doesn't need to use addition namespace `System.Drawing.SystemColors`.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.BackColor = default(Color);
```

Seems to be the color that the form designer uses...

Answer (score 1):

Another way for example is to use the `Transapernt` to set the color of control `Parent`

```
this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```